# javascript native equivalent to .each & .attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, native

I have following jQuery script I am trying to convert to native javascript.

```
function isElementInViewport(el) {
  //special bonus for those using jQuery
  if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
    el = el[0];
  }
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    rect.top >= 0 &&
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
  );
}

$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  $(".anchor").each(function (idx, el) {
    if ( isElementInViewport(el) ) {
      if (window.history.pushState) {
        var urlHash = "#" + $(el).attr("id");
        window.history.pushState(null, null, urlHash);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I have tried,

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var anchor = document.querySelectorAll(".anchor");
  anchor.forEach(function (idx, el) {
    if ( isElementInViewport(el) ) {
      if (window.history.pushState) {
        var urlHash = "#" + $(el).attr("id");
        window.history.pushState(null, null, urlHash);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

but I get various console errors saying xxxxx is not a function, etc.  I guess I am not converting the jQuery iteration (.each) correctly & I also do not know how to convert $(el) & .attr.

I wish this was simple as changing .attr to => setAttribute but it's not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated it.

Comment: `function (idx, el)` should be `function (el, idx)`

Comment: `$(el).attr("id")` should be `el.getAttribute("id")`, or better `el.id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close - `forEach`'s first argument is the *element you're iterating over*, not the index. (In jQuery, the arguments are in reverse - the first argument is the *index* and the second argument is the *item*).

For the `.attr('id')` part, you can just access the plain `.id` property of the element:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var anchor = document.querySelectorAll(".anchor");
  anchor.forEach(function(el) {
    if (isElementInViewport(el)) {
      if (window.history.pushState) {
        var urlHash = "#" + el.id;
        window.history.pushState(null, null, urlHash);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Also note that `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`. `NodeList.prototype.forEach` is *convenient* to be able to use, but it's a somewhat new feature, and generally isn't supported in browsers older than 2016 - to ensure compatibility for older browsers, either use a polyfill, or call `Array.prototype.forEach` instead:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll(".anchor"),
    function(el) {
      if (isElementInViewport(el) && window.history.pushState) {
        var urlHash = "#" + el.id;
        window.history.pushState(null, null, urlHash);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: thank you so much!!!  stackoverflow is telling me I can't accept your answer though. LOL  don't know why.  I will come back in a bit & try to accept it again. hope it works. (I don't see why this is not a good answer. hmm....)

Comment: stackoverflow is allowing me to accept your answer now.  accepted it.  Thanks!!